# Replacing the Internal Time Capsule Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-capsule

I'm trying to install a new hard drive in my TC after the original one died, but to no avail.

I bought a 1.0TB 3.5 WesternDigital SATA disk and formatted it for OS X using a SATA-USB connector. It worked and the disk is usable. BUT as soon as I plug it back in TC and power it up, TC displays its amber non-flashing light and its wifi stops working.

However if I remove the HD, the wifi gets back on its feet...

May some TC genius come to the rescue of my troubled soul.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the TC format the drive. If you can't make that happen using a reset + reconfigure from the AirPort utility, you might have an incompatible drive (i.e. Needs more power or cannot be used due to incompatible features).

It's not going to work like an external drive that happens to be built in, the TC OS needs to manage the disk. OS X can read such disks, so it might seem like any normal formatted disk if you hooked up the old one.

If you still have the old drive, you might have more luck cloning it to the new one prior to installing it.

Also, if wifi doesn't work, ethernet might still work, especially if the Time Capsule needs a reset.

Comment: Weird. Airport can see the TC on the network when I plug it via Ethernet... but only if I remove the internal drive. Same applies to the old drive, untouched since its been defunct. Hmmm...

Comment: One more thing: the HD "clicks" (head displacement) each second. So the TC seems to try to connect to it periodically.

Comment: It might also mean it tries to power up, but fails. Or both drives are equally broken, also possible. A defect in the TC that causes disks to be unusable is possible too. Have you tried resetting with the new disk inserted?

Comment: Yes I did. Many times.

Comment: Have you tried a blank disk instead of a formatted one?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried, in fact. As this didn't work, I told myself I should then format it with the Mac before. Didn't work either.

Comment: I should add that I connected the HD via USB to the TC, and everything works perfectly... But I would really prefer using the slot in the TC. Aargh, cruel universe...

Comment: Seems like the sata interface might be broken. Any chance you can upload pictures of the front and back of the internal pcb?

Comment: John, I salute your persistence! Many thanks, I'll try to get you some pictures ASAP.

Comment: John, here's the pictures I could take with what time I had: [Pic1](http://jeanlemoignan.ca/IMG_0295.JPG), [Pic2](http://jeanlemoignan.ca/IMG_0295.JPG). Everything seems fine. Getting the card out to take a picture of the other side seemed more daunting.